# Unicode character name in variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I want to create an unicode string using the name of a character, like this (found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)) :

```
>>> "\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}"  
'\u0394'
```

but having the name of the character in a variable. Like

```
myChar = "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA"
myString = "\N{myChar}"   # causes SyntaxError: (unicode error)
```

I tried many things based on format(), nothing worked.
Anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unicodedata.lookup`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup).

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> my_char = "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA"
>>> unicodedata.lookup(my_char)
'Δ'
```